# Bookmarklet: Go to embed YouTube page

Tags: javascript, youtube, embed, switch-statement, bookmarklet

Is there any way to make a JavaScript bookmarklet for Google Chrome that when clicked switches the current page from :

```
www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEOID
```

*or*

```
www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEOID&feature=related
```

*or any other type of YouTube URL*

**to**

```
www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID
```

I spent almost an hour trying (and discovering).

Thanks in advance for being generous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.location = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + document.location.href.match(/[&?]v=([^&#]*)/i)[1]
```

as a bookmarklet

```
javascript:document.location%20%3D%20'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2F'%20%2B%20document.location.href.match(%2F%5B%26%3F%5Dv%3D(%5B%5E%26%23%5D*)%2Fi)%5B1%5D%0A%0A
```